# Why isn't part of my code running, even though it is in a function and the print statements above it works?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, loops, google-cloud-firestore

I am running an angular project, where this file will grab data from a firebase database and the code at the bottom of the getStatistics() function will populate a map(pairArray) with the info on the different pairs of visit data that the database contains.

The problem is that the code at the bottom of the getStatistics() function, denoted by the line of backslashes will not run. Well, nothing in a for or if-else loop will run. The console.log() function will work though, so I am not sure why the code will not run. It will run if I put it higher up in the function though, underneath all the math that calculates percentages.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// Firestore imports 
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Observable,of, from, Timestamp } from 'rxjs';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { NgForm, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

/*
 getStatistics function:

The goal of this function is to iterate through the database and get the required statistics.
The structure of the database:
  visits IDs are stored as collections, files, in the firestore database.
  Visits of the same ID are stored as documents inside each collection.
The function iterates through each collection, ID,  and counts how many visits are stored in each ID,
 then it increments the AgencyCounter for each agency that was detected in the collection.
The iteration over collections and documents in the database is done by using the "payload.forEach" method

TODO
1. Identify group visits and exclude them from the getStatistics()
2. correct the common pair and common triplet algorithm. Agencies should be sorted based on how many times 
   they appreared in the pair or triplet visits.

 */

interface  Visit{
  code: number;
}

// interface that defines the agency visit structure
interface  AencyVisit{
  AgencyID: string;
  code: string;
  time: Timestamp<any>;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

   // Connect Agency to Firebase collection
   visitCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Visit>;
   visits: Observable<Visit[]>;

   // Statistics fields
  totalNumVisits = 0;
  totalMultipleVisits = 0;
  highest = 0;
   totalNumPairVisits = 0 ;
   percentageOfPairVisits = 0;
   totalNumTripletVisits = 0;
    percentageOfTripletVisits = 0;
  totalNum5PlusVisits = 0;
  lastHighest = 0;
  percentageOf5PlusVisits = 0;
  totalNum4Visits = 0;
  percentageOf4Visits = 0;
  keyHolder = "";
  valueAdjuster = 0;
  timer = null;
  k = 0;
   commonPairs = new Array();
   commonPair = new Array();
   commonTriplets = new Array();
   commonTriplet = new Array();
   values = new Array();
   //this.values.push(rand = new Array());
   //visitsy = new Array<Observable<Visit[]>>();

   agencyCounterPerID=0;
  //  counterArray ={1:0, 2:0 , 3:0}; //  key represents duplicate or triplet of agencies, value = their number
   // 32 max agency limit per visit - hopefully no one should ever reach this
   counterArray = [0,0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]   
   //pairArray = new Map<Array<Object>, number>(); 
   pairArray = new Map<string, number>(); 
   multiples = 0;
   //  mostCommonPairList and mostCommonTripletList will be used to filter the most common pair and triplet agencies
   mostCommonPairList = {"DEMO-B-Geese":1, "DEMO-A-Berges":1, "DEMO-C1-Gentle":1, "DEMO-C2-Crunke":1,"DEMO-C3-Girls":1, "DEMO-D-Literacy":1, "DEMO-E-Life":1,"DEMO-F-Pools":1};
   mostCommonTripletList = {"DEMO-B-Geese":1, "DEMO-A-Berges":1, "DEMO-C1-Gentle":1, "DEMO-C2-Crunke":1,"DEMO-C3-Girls":1, "DEMO-D-Literacy":1, "DEMO-E-Life":1,"DEMO-F-Pools":1};
   agencyList = new Array(); 
   IDField: Observable<any>;

   // Percentage calculations
   pctMultipleAgencyVisits: number;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // console.log("a");
    this.getStatistics();
  }

  getStatistics(): void{
    const visitArray = this.afs.collection("visits").snapshotChanges();

    visitArray.subscribe(payload => {
      this.totalNumVisits = 0;
      this.totalNumPairVisits = 0;
      this.percentageOfPairVisits = 0;
      this.totalNumTripletVisits = 0;
      this.percentageOfTripletVisits = 0;
      this.totalNum5PlusVisits = 0;
      this.percentageOf5PlusVisits = 0;
      this.totalNum4Visits = 0;
      this.percentageOf4Visits = 0;
      const values = [];



      payload.forEach( item => {
        const visit = item.payload.doc.data() as Visit;
        //const values = [];
        this.totalNumVisits += 1;
        this.timer = null;

        // getting visited frequencies
        const visitedAgencies = this.afs.collection(visit.code.toString()).snapshotChanges();
        visitedAgencies.subscribe(payload => {


          this.agencyCounterPerID = payload.length;
          this.k = 0;
          payload.forEach( item => {
            const agencyVisit = item.payload.doc.data() as AencyVisit; 
            this.agencyList.push(agencyVisit.AgencyID);

            // Add visit pairs to nested list for later analysis
            if (this.agencyCounterPerID == 2){
                if (this.k == 0){
                    this.values.push(new Array(agencyVisit.AgencyID.toString()));
                }

                if (this.k == 1){
                    this.values[this.values.length - 1].push(agencyVisit.AgencyID.toString());
                }

                this.k = 1;
            }
          });

          console.log("list", this.agencyList.toString());

          this.counterArray[this.agencyCounterPerID]+=1;
          if (this.agencyCounterPerID == 2) {
            this.totalNumPairVisits += 1;
            var result2 = this.agencyList.includes(this.agencyList[i]);
            this.mostCommonPairList[this.agencyList[i]] += 1;
          } else if (this.agencyCounterPerID == 3) {
            this.totalNumTripletVisits += 1;
            var result3 = this.agencyList.includes(this.agencyList[i]);
            this.mostCommonTripletList[this.agencyList[i]] += 1;
          } else if (this.agencyCounterPerID == 4) {
            this.totalNum4Visits += 1;
          } else if (this.agencyCounterPerID >= 5) {
            this.totalNum5PlusVisits += 1;
          }

          for (var i=2; i<this.counterArray.length; i++) {
           this.multiples+= this.counterArray[i];
          }

          // percentages
          this.pctMultipleAgencyVisits = this.totalNumVisits / this.counterArray[2];//this.multiples;
          this.totalMultipleVisits = this.totalNumPairVisits + this.totalNumTripletVisits + this.totalNum4Visits + this.totalNum5PlusVisits;
          this.percentageOfPairVisits = this.totalNumPairVisits / this.totalMultipleVisits * 100 ;
          this.percentageOfTripletVisits = this.totalNumTripletVisits / this.totalMultipleVisits * 100;
          this.percentageOf4Visits = this.totalNum4Visits / this.totalMultipleVisits * 100;
          this.percentageOf5PlusVisits = this.totalNum5PlusVisits / this.totalMultipleVisits * 100;
          this.commonPair.push(this.agencyList[0]);
          this.commonPair.push(this.agencyList[1]);
          this.commonTriplet.push(this.agencyList[0]);
          this.commonTriplet.push(this.agencyList[0]);

          this.agencyCounterPerID =0;
          //empty the array
          this.agencyList.length = 0;

        });

    });

  });

    console.log("working");

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //format pairs into sorted strings
    for (let u = 0; u < this.values.length; u++){
        this.values[u].sort();
        this.values[u].toString();
        console.log("here1");
    }

    //add values to map(dictionary)
    for (let p = 0; p < this.values.length; p++){
        if (this.pairArray.has(this.values[p].toString()) == false){
            this.pairArray.set(this.values[p].toString(), 1);
            console.log("here2");
        }
        else if (this.pairArray.has(this.values[p].toString()) == true){
            //return this.pairArray;
            for (let a = 0; a < 10000; a++){
                if (this.pairArray.get(this.values[p].toString()) == a){
                    this.keyHolder = this.values[p].toString();
                    this.valueAdjuster = a + 1;

                    this.pairArray.delete(this.values[p].toString());
                    console.log("here3");
                }
                console.log("here4");
            }
            this.pairArray.set(this.keyHolder, this.valueAdjuster);
            console.log("here5");
        }
    }

    //find number of occurences of highest frequency pair
    this.highest = 0;
    for (let [key, value] of this.pairArray) {
        console.log("here7");
        if (value > this.highest){
            this.highest = value;
            console.log("here6");
        }
    }

    //add highest frequency pair to list
    for (let [key, value] of this.pairArray) {
        console.log("here9");
        if (value == this.highest && this.commonPairs.indexOf(key) == -1){
            this.commonPairs.push(key);
            console.log("here8");
            //break;
        }
    }

    //find number of occurences of second highest frequency pair
    this.lastHighest = this.highest;
    this.highest = 0;
    for (let [key, value] of this.pairArray) {
        console.log("here11");
        if (value > this.highest && value != this.lastHighest){
            this.highest = value;
            console.log("here10");
        }
    }

    //add second highest frequency pair to list
    for (let [key, value] of this.pairArray) {
        console.log("here13");
        if (value == this.highest && this.commonPairs.indexOf(key) == -1){
            this.commonPairs.push(key);
            console.log("here12");
        }
    }

    // Prints out the dictionary
    for (let [key, value] of this.pairArray) {
        console.log("here14");
        console.log("key: ", key.toString(), ", value: ", value);
    }
    console.log("end run");

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //console.log("values", this.values);

  // console.log(this.counterArray[1] , " visit for " , 1 , "agencies");
  // console.log(this.counterArray[2] , " visit for " , 2 , "agencies");
  // console.log(this.counterArray[3] , " visit for " , 3 , "agencies");

    //console.log("len", this.values.length);

    //console.log("counter: ", this.counterArray);



    //console.log("cp: ", typeof(this.commonPairs[0]));
    //console.log("v: ", typeof(this.values[0]));
    //console.log("values: ", this.values);

  }

  formatPercent(num) {
    return Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code is a lot to take in but it looks like the for loops at the bottom are being called outside of the subscribes.  Since this is asynchronous code, the values in the for loops are undefined or empty when the functions run because the values you are getting from your firebase calls are not yet returned.  When you call subscribe, the code execution moves on while a second thread waits for the response to execute the code inside the subscribe.